# hide control when xsp resides in iframe

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to hide certain controls when an xpage is embedded in an iframe. How can I do this?

Based upon some recommendation on this site I tried:

In client side JavaScript I have available:

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[if (window.frameElement) {
  //in iframe
  var field = document.getElementById("#{id:NavBarOption}");
  alert(field.id)
  field.value = "hide";
}
else {
  //NOT in iframe
  var field = document.getElementById("#{id:NavBarOption}");
   alert(field.id)
  field.value = "";
}]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

This should set an inputbox control which has a partial refresh in the onchange event for :

```
<xp:inputText id="NavBarOption"
        value="${javascript:viewScope.NavBarOption}">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="type" value="hidden"></xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="body" immediate="true"
            execMode="partial" execId="body">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>
```

The inputbox control is bound to a scope Variable. This scope Variabel will be used in controls or custom control for the rendered property e.g.:

```
<xc:ccNavBar id="ccNavBar">
            <xc:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:return true;
var hide = viewScope.showNavBar;

if (hide !=""){
    //return false;
}
else{
    //return true;
}}]]></xc:this.rendered>
        </xc:ccNavBar>
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be a bit weird, but maybe I'm not getting the whole picture. Let me split my answer into two sections:

Section 1: possible solution for your original task (hide controls based on the fact whether they are part of an iframe - or not):

just gave it a try with a very simple approach:

1. built a page including an iframe whose src attribute is calling
   another xsp
2. the src attribute also contains a querystring; I used
   "?status=inIframe"
3. also built a custom control querying said
   queryString
4. to prove that everything works as expected I used the
   CC twice: once inside the xsp called by the iFrame, and once
   directly inside the main page.

Here's the code:

CustomControl `ccInner`; has a boolean CC property "`isInIframe`":

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel
        id="pnInnerContainer">
        <xp:label
            id="label1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.isInIframe?"I'm inside an iframe":"I'm outside an iframe"}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.isInIframe?"color:red;":"color:blue;"}]]></xp:this.style>
        </xp:label>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

The "inner" xsp includes ccInner; the boolean CC property is calculated based on `context.getUrlParameter("status")`:

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xc:ccInner>
        <xc:this.isInIframe><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.getUrlParameter("status")=="iniframe"?true:false}]]></xc:this.isInIframe>
    </xc:ccInner>
</xp:view>
```

The "outer" xsp contains the iframe definition as well as a 2nd instance of the Custom control, again caluculating the CC property based on urlParameter:

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:panel
        id="iframeContainer"
        style="padding:10px;border:1px grey solid;">
        <iframe
            id="myIframe"
            frameborder="0"
            style="width:300px;height:30px;border:1px red solid;padding:5px;"
            src="testinnerifr.xsp?status=iniframe">
        </iframe>
        <xc:ccInner>
            <xc:this.isInIframe><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.getUrlParameter("status")=="iniframe"?true:false}]]></xc:this.isInIframe>
        </xc:ccInner>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Works fine for me: the label inside the CC shows the expected value in the expected color.

Section 2: some remarks regarding your code

1. using `document.getElementById()` in **dojo based pages** is said to be not very efficient; try to use `dojo.byId()` or `XSP.getElementById()` instead.
2. you are binding your viewScope onPageLoad directive using "`$`" instead of "`#`" ("`${javascript:viewScope.NavBarOption}`". Is there a specific reason why you want to prevent the value to be updated upon refreshing the page? This leads to the fact that the rendered property will be recalculated during multiple phases of your page's lifecycle but the value will only be updated once on page load. Not very effective to say the least
3. And why don't you bind the scope var to the field using SSJS instead of using EL as in "`#{viewScope.NavBarOption}`"?